# Regex to match subdomain (if exists) and domain (in nginx)

Tags: regex, nginx

I need a regex to extract the subdomain (if it exists) and the domain with TLD.
This is for an nginx config so please strictly regex is needed.

Examples:

```
www.a0.example.com 
www.example.com
www.example.org
```

- Example line 1 should match `a0` and `example.com` into groups
- Example line 2 should match only `example.com` into a group since the subdomain is
  absent
- Example line 3 should match only `example.org` into a group
  because the subdomain is absent as well

The group numbers should be consistant so `$0` will always return the subdomain or blank if it does not exist, and `$1` will always return the domain. The `www` will always be present.

Any regex wizards out there that can wave their wand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a test regex in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -lne '/^www\.([^\.]+\.)?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$/ and print "1=$1 2=$2"' file
1=a0. 2=example.com 
1=    2=example.com
1=    2=example.org
```

Regex :

```
/^www\.([^\.]+\.)?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$/
```